# API authentification token

Tags: api, http, authentication, twitter, token

I have recently learnt about API and started using them for learning purpose.
I have tried the twitter API,but there is something I don't understand

**Process of sending tweets with an API**

- Get your API token (need to tell a lot of informations and wait some time before it's validated)
- Make http post request with the token to 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update
- Tweet posted successfully

**Process of sending tweets with your browser:**

- Create an account (don't need that much information, it's instant)
- Login, write a tweet
- When you click on submit, a http post request is sent (to the same url that above) and there is a Bearer token in the request header
- Tweet posted successfully

So that leads to my question, why should I contact twitter to have an API token, if I can have one just by creating an account ?
How do twitter back-end know that the request is coming from a browser (normal use) or if it's coming from a third part app ?

Answer (score 0):

The direct answer to your question is that the only approved way (inside of the Terms of Service) of sending Tweets programmatically is to use the official API.

There are a variety of ways in which websites and web services can detect browser automation or usage, and that's not really a question for a programming community like Stack Overflow.

What exactly are you trying to do, and why would you choose not to use the supported official API?

Comment: Actually I did use the official API, but now I'm creating a front end app with a back end and I don't want user to bypass my front and plug directly to my back end ( even if it's more likely to never happen)